# CakePHP 3 refresh page based on current database state

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, is there a possibility to refresh page (view) on fly only if a selected table from database has changed (for example new rows are available)? How can I detect if database has changed its state and refresh if a user is on the selected page? Is there any possibility for this?

Comment: yes its possible, try to implement libs like http://socketo.me/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I know the concept of sockets from other languages e.g. Java. However I do not have any knowledge how should I "press trigger" of socket import in PHP without clicking any button or reloading any page. Would it be possible for you to show me the simple "trigger" without reloading the website page or clicking any button? The socket itself I will somehow handle, this will not be a problem.

Comment: read: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html , https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#event-list . next implement socket libs to send signal on changes (save, delete) to clients. On client listen signals and on change run some actions.

Comment: Thank you, I will check yur suggestion - I need 3-4 days for it, and I will write back my result.